# Accessing Delphi Routine Local variable

Tags: delphi

How can I access the local variable of a routine from outside. Like this one e.g

```
procedure TForm1.CalculateTax(var Amount: Double);
var 
  Tax : Double;
begin
  Tax := Amount*2.5/100;
end;
```

Comment: ... or a by-reference parameter: `procedure TForm1.CalculateTax(var Tax: Double; Amount: Double);`.

Comment: @user1429045: is it a bit clearer now?  You need a "variable" when you need to "remember something" (for example, the operands in an arithmetic expression).  Once you have a "result", you can 1) store it in a global variable (that everyone can see), 2) pass it back in a "var" reference variable or 3) pass it back as the "result" of a "function".  Option 3 (using a function) is generally preferred, if at all possible.

Answer (score 6):

You can't access a local variable from outside the procedure it's declared in.

The best solution is to change your `procedure` to a `function`, and have it return the value.

Change your `TForm1` declaration

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  procedure CalculateTax(var Amount: Double);
```

to

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  function CalculateTax(const Amount: Double): Double;
```

Change the implementation from

```
procedure TForm1.CalculateTax(var Amount: Double);
var 
  Tax : Double;
begin
  Tax := Amount*2.5/100;
end;
```

to

```
function TForm1.CalculateTax(const Amount: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := Amount*2.5/100;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
Tax := CalculateTax(YourAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

My $0.02:

1) I would make this a "function" rather than a "procedure" (because it's purpose is to "return a value" - the tax amount)

2) I would not hard-code either the "amount" or "tax rate" inside the routine

3) I would not "overload" (give multiple meanings to) the variable "amount"

```
// Better
function TForm1.CalculateTax(purchaseAmount, taxRate: Currency) : Currency;
begin
  Result := purchaseAmount * (taxRate / 100.0);
end;
```